# Is there any Way to fetch API with Static IP Address

Tags: ip, static-ip-address, fetching-strategy

Actually I am trying to make a discord bot Using Clash of Clans API, but the API have keys which are restricted to only whitelisted IP Address(es), and unlike MongoDB it does not support `0.0.0.0` and My IP Address Changes a A lot. Is there any way where I can fetch it with Static IP Address. Like I give my API key to another API and then it fetches for me with a static IP Address?